# Merge two pandas dataframes on not exactly matching timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, merge, time-series, dataframe

I tried searching the site for a good way to implement this (tried some ideas with binning and time series too) but still could not find a suitable soultion.

Here is the problem

I have two dataframes:

```
    index   name    time            price
1,  AAA,    11:37:09.359479,    58.480000,10
2,  ABC,    11:37:15.403268,    0.5000000,3
3,  ABB,    11:37:15.491515,    0.4500000,2
4,  AAA,    11:37:15.604864,    0.5000000,1
5,  ABC,    11:37:16.628756,    0.1800000,20
6,  ABD,    11:37:21.083105,    0.8000000,7
7,  AAA,    11:37:21.423480,    79.030000,10


index   name    time            price

1,  ABB,    11:37:15.491525,    0.4500000,2
2,  AAA,    11:37:15.604884,    0.5000000,1
3,  ABC,    11:37:16.628796,    0.1800000,20
```

As you can see index 3,4,5 from dataframe 1 has corresponding indexes 1,2,3 from dataftame 2

I need to merge these to dataframes into one on 'time' column so that for records 3,4,5 from dataframe 1 indexes 1,2,3 from dataframe 2 were on the right.

This should be the result:

```
index_x name_x  time_x          price_x         name_y  time_y          price_y
1,  AAA,    11:37:09.359479,    58.480000,10    Nan ...
2,  ABC,    11:37:15.403268,    0.5000000,3     Nan ..  
3,  ABB,    11:37:15.491515,    0.4500000,2     ABB,    11:37:15.491525,    0.4500000,2
4,  AAA,    11:37:15.604864,    0.5000000,1     AAA,    11:37:15.604884,    0.5000000,1
5,  ABC,    11:37:16.628756,    0.1800000,20    ABC,    11:37:16.628796,    0.1800000,20
6,  ABD,    11:37:21.083105,    0.8000000,7     Nan ..
7,  AAA,    11:37:21.423480,    79.030000,10    Nan ..
```

I have troubles because time is not EXACTLY the same (look at the last 2 microseconds). Is there a good way to merge it the way to merge these on time with time not exactly matching, but given some matching threshold maybe? Also there should only be no more than ONE match for each record.

Please let me know if it is clear.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Assuming your time is a string, one thing you could simply do is just strip out the last two or three digits of the time and then perform the join.  e.g. x['time']=x['time'][:-3]

Comment: This was my first idea, but this would produce some duplicated joins.. I need a way to uniquely join those records, meaning find a single closest matching time (smallest absolute difference) for each record.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately these "close matches" rarely have a super simple solution in pandas, but this isn't too bad.  What you can do is start with @CharlieHaley's solution, but then put it in a loop such that you take the most precise match possible and discard the less precise matches.

Of course, that still leaves you to decide which precision levels to use (as specified in 'decimal_range').  I started the range at 7 to keep the output concise but you'd want to start it at 1 and then decide how high you want to run it as higher numbers allow less precise matches.

(Note: I'm assuming your initial dataframes are 'df1' and 'df2' and that 'time' is a string, if not you need to first convert it to a string.)

```
decimal_range = range(7,9)

df1 = df1.reset_index()   # this creates column 'index' later used for
                          # dropping duplicates.  depending on your
                          # goals, may want to do for df2 instead of df1  
df3=pd.DataFrame()

for i in decimal_range:
    df1['time2'] = df1['time'].str[:-i]
    df2['time2'] = df2['time'].str[:-i]
    df3 = df3.append( df1.merge(df2,on=['name','time2'], how='inner'), )

df4 = df3.drop_duplicates(subset=['index','name'])
```

Showing the intermediate output may make this more clear.  When merging at `i=7`, there are 3 matches, but at `i=8` there are 4 matches.  The 'time2' column displays the precision that was used for the match.

```
df3

   index name           time_x  price_x     time2           time_y  price_y
0      2  ABB  11:37:15.491515     0.45  11:37:15  11:37:15.491525     0.45
1      3  AAA  11:37:15.604864     0.50  11:37:15  11:37:15.604884     0.50
2      4  ABC  11:37:16.628756     0.18  11:37:16  11:37:16.628796     0.18
0      1  ABC  11:37:15.403268     0.50   11:37:1  11:37:16.628796     0.18
1      4  ABC  11:37:16.628756     0.18   11:37:1  11:37:16.628796     0.18
2      2  ABB  11:37:15.491515     0.45   11:37:1  11:37:15.491525     0.45
3      3  AAA  11:37:15.604864     0.50   11:37:1  11:37:15.604884     0.50
```

After accumulating the matches, just drop duplicates to keep the more precise matches.

```
df4

   index name           time_x  price_x     time2           time_y  price_y
0      2  ABB  11:37:15.491515     0.45  11:37:15  11:37:15.491525     0.45
1      3  AAA  11:37:15.604864     0.50  11:37:15  11:37:15.604884     0.50
2      4  ABC  11:37:16.628756     0.18  11:37:16  11:37:16.628796     0.18
0      1  ABC  11:37:15.403268     0.50   11:37:1  11:37:16.628796     0.18
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this is a good idea, I might try this method to solve this

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is splitting my dataframes into equal bins and then merging them on bin Ids.

One drawback of this is that I can only do that for 'common'/'shared' timeintervals in these two dataframes (for indexes 3,4,5 in first dataframe).

Also there could be several records in the same bin, in this case I just use the last record from both sides to be merged.

so this is what i do (my dataframes names are onTrade1 and onTrade2):

```
commonFirstTime = max (onTrade1['exchangeTime'].min(), onTrade2['exchangeTime'].min())
commonLastTime = min (onTrade1['exchangeTime'].max(), onTrade2['exchangeTime'].max())


bins = numpy.linspace(commonFirstTime, commonLastTime, ((commonLastTime - commonFirstTime) / 1000))

groups1 = onTrade1.groupby(numpy.digitize(onTrade1['exchangeTime'], bins))
groups2 = onTrade2.groupby(numpy.digitize(onTrade2['exchangeTime'], bins))
```

Then I can simply merge groups1 with groups2 on common index.